# Twitter4j getHomeTimeline(Paging) is not retrieving what i want

Tags: paging, twitter4j, timeline

My objective is to get tweets from a Timeline, just one at a time, using Paging within getHomeTimeline method, and starting from the newest.

It happens that when I do not use Paging I get the expected 20 results, but when I use Paging to get just one tweet I get 0 results.

This is my code snippet:

```
Twitter twitter = getTwitterObject();
Long maxid = prefs.getLong(MAXTWEETID2, Long.MAX_VALUE); //Initially is MAX_VALUE
Long sinceid = prefs.getLong(MINTWEETID2, 1L); //Initially is 1
Paging paging = new Paging(1, 1, sinceid, maxid);
statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
```

I want to use the previous Paging with sinceId and maxId because I want to play with cursoring to constrain my query in successive lookups.

But I have also tried using:

```
Paging paging = new Paging(1, 1);
```

Same void result.

I have searched the web and this forum without getting any clue about constraints regarding the use of Paging while searching the Timeline of a user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is something to do with setting `max_id` to `Long.MAX_VALUE`. If instead you set `max_id` to `Long.MAX_VALUE - 1` you should see results. This may be a bug in the API.

I would suggest not setting the `count` so low. API calls are expensive and you will hit rate limits quickly. For example, this API call only allows 15 calls in each 'rate limit window' (currently 15 minutes). You can find out more about [rate limiting here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1).

Finally, `getHomeTimeline(Paging)` does not support all of the parameters offered by `Paging`. It does support `since_id`, `max_id` and `count` but not `page` - it will be ignored. This is the case for most of the API calls in Twitter4J. You can find out what parameters are supported per API call by referring to [Twitter4J's API Support Matrix](http://twitter4j.org/en/api-support.html) documentation.